# How to check if a string only contains certain characters in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot that allows you to play hangman. I need to check if a string only contains lowercase english letters and hyphens ("-").

I know how to check if it contains or doesn't contain certain characters, but how do I check if it *only* contains specific characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression with a character set of only those characters you want to permit would work:

```js
const test = str => /^[a-z-]+$/.test(str);

console.log(
  test('foo'),
  test('Bar')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression to validate if a string ONLY contains a specific character.

If you want to check if a string only contains 'a','b','c' characters then find the example below.

```
function checkCharacter(str){
  return new RegExp("[a,b,c]+$").test(str)
}

console.log(checkCharacter("ab")); //true
console.log(checkCharacter("abd")); //false
console.log(checkCharacter("aB")); //false
```